# Passing a parameter value for like

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table ter (
  ID number, 
  category varchar2(250 byte),
  name varchar2(250 byte)
); 

insert into ter values (1, 'amd-visual theraphy','john');
insert into ter values (1, 'amd-visual theraphy','mike');
insert into ter values (2, 'amd-autmatic theraphy','mike');
insert into ter values (3, 'amd-autmatic theraphy','drane');
insert into ter values (3, 'cmd autmatic theraphy', 'traverse');
insert into ter values (3, 'amd-dramatic theraphy','drane');
insert into ter values (3, 'cmd-dropertic theraphy', 'traverse');
insert into ter values (5,'qwd-dropertic visual-theraphy','drones');
insert into ter values (5,'qwd-aromatic-theraphy','drones');
insert into ter values (3, 'other', 'traverse');
insert into ter values (3, 'other', 'traverse');
```

1: &category is null  display all records

2: &category is not null and if i enter category  =visual,autmatic  then display respectively

3 &category is not null and if i enter category =dramatic it should display dramtic and dropertic ignoring other results;

as dramatic and dropertic is the requirement where the user want to see and ignoring the if partial value matches with visual and autmatic contains

how to obtain this result
this is what one gave the solution to me but still i want to ignore the visual containing dropetic

```
   select *
    from   ter t cross join (select '&category' as my_categ from dual) m
 where  m.my_categ is null
or  m.my_categ in ('visual', 'autmatic', 'dramtic') and t.category like '%' 
 || m.my_categ || '%'
 or  m.my_categ = 'dramtic' and t.category like '%dropertic%' ;
```

Comment: Duplicate ID's?!?

Comment: The values you mention in points 2 and 3 don't match the actual category values; so you want to have a single substitution variable which represents multiple partial category names at once, and find records where the category is 'like' any of those partial values? So point 2 should match the first five rows you inserted, right? But then why in point 3 does 'dramatic' match the categories that contain 'dropertic'? (Or, indeed, 'dramtic', which I assume is a typo.)

Comment: yes its a category like partial values and dramtic is typo alex

Comment: I jus added one more row in it where it has visual and dramatic but when i enter dramatic it shouldn`t display that one

Comment: @JOHNPaul - why *shouldn't* it display that one, when there is a partial match? And why *should* it display the ones with 'dropertic'? I don't understand your logic. Please edit the question to explain your logic/rules, and show the expected output for when the substitution variable is not null.

Comment: I got the solution almost i was wondering how do i ignore the value having partial value in visual with dropertic edited.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your data model a bit.
Instead of saving categories as a space separated string, i'd better move them to separate table.

```
create table category(
  ter_id number,
  name varchar(250 bytes)
);
```

where `ter_id` is the same as `ID` in your `ter` column.

This table should contain records like:

```
insert into category values (1, 'amd-visual');
insert into category values (1, 'therapy');
-- etc.
```

Implying above your query will be something like:

```
select t.*, c.* 
from ter t, category c
where t.id = c.ter_id
  and category in ('therapy', 'visual');
  -- etc...
```

If you really need to satisfy criteria:

> if category is null display all records

it's easy to implement just adding
record with empty category `name` to table `category`:

```
insert into category values (1, null);
insert into category values (2, null);
```

-- etc.